# React: check user authenticated by the front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, passport.js

How can I check if a token is true? I have an api with laravel passport and the front with react, the user puts email and password, the api checks and if you have user in the db it generates a token and stores it in the local storage, I have a private route, and for that I would need to know if the user is authenticated, the question is, how do I verify that the token is true? Previously I did a logic, but not worked, because if someone opened the console and put any value in the token, it returned true and the person was free to access the system.

I would use this function on my private route, if the user was authenticated I would release the route, so I would need to check on the front, if you have a better idea and can give me an example, thank you in advance!

Comment: You absolutely *have* to check the validity in the backend. Your validation should include some type of secret key for decoding, which should never be exposed to the frontend. Remember that clientside code is visible to everyone that visits your page. Front end token validation implies exposing that secret key

Answer (score 0):

I usually check the token to the back end server. 
So at the front end I use a component that send the token to the backend (usually at componentDidMount) if the response is true I will render the private component and if it is false I will use redirect to the login page. 
This is the link https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0):

Token couldn't be authenticated from frontend, frontend could save token in localStorage, you need to send the token on backend to authenticate it.

Comment: And how would I do that? can you give an example?

Comment: Developers usually do by sending token in API headers and at server side for each API they check authentication of token

Answer (score 0):

First of all understand the purpose of the problem. create logic that can used to validate the token. basically renew your token mean renew you session and the user has to refreshed with the latest data for the panel.

> 1. Token cannot be stored at the client side, it can be initiated and processed at client side but you must always validate, if system feels invalid make a force logout or make the session expired.
> 2. If you have a private route which navigate the user to another location make sure then add a additional to use the same token or generate a different token.create the route to check the flag and retrieve the existing token and utilize.
> 3. Clear the existing one and create the new one to update the system. Front end only should have navigation path if validated only approve. No client side authentication.